# Multi-line int output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print `int` in multi-line

Here is my python code:

```
a=int(3)
b=int(5)
c=a+b,"\n",a-b,"\n",a*b,"\n"
print(c)
```

Output I want to achieve:

```
 8
-2
 15
```

Output I'm getting:

```
(8, '\n', 2, '\n', 15, '\n')
```

Will someone help me out with this?

Comment: `print(a + b, a - b, a * b, sep='\n')`…

Comment: Are you  looking for ``print(*c)``?

Comment: can you explain your answer how this working? because it's working

Comment: what does ```print(*c)``` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iteratively print the elements of `c`.

```
a = int(3)
b = int(5)
c = a+b, a-b, a*b

for i in c:
    print(i)
```

Comment: yes bro this is what I want is it any way to do this without loop?

Comment: What's the exact requirement? Why can't you perform a loop?

Comment: because I'm trying to make it simple as I can!

Comment: In that case, why not just store each calculation as an indivual variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
a=3
b=3
c=str(a+b)+"\n" + str(a-b) + "\n" + str(a*b) + "\n"
print(c)
```

Try this one.

Comment: no bro I can't convert int into str

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c=str(a+b)+"\n" + str(a-b) + "\n" + str(a*b) + "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

when writing :
`c = a+b,"\n",a-b,"\n",a*b,"\n"`
you actually creating a tuple, separated by commas,

that's why when printing this is the output you get.
this is why @Bashton answer require iterations on c (as a list)

if you with replace the commas with + you actually create one string concatenated (by + signs). that's why when you print it only takes one print.
that's why

`c=str(a+b)+"\n" + str(a-b) + "\n" + str(a*b) + "\n"`

solution would only require one print.

Comment: Note that ``c`` is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: sorry, i met tuple, and of course tuple is also iterable. fixed my answer, thanks

Comment: @MisterMiyagi can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: @SushantUniversity Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#tuples): _"Tuples may be constructed in a number of ways: ... Separating items with commas: `a, b, c` ..."_